# In Composer require dev-master#1.0.0 pulling latest commit

Tags: git, composer-php

I have a metapackage that works fine with required tag like this:

```
"vendor/module": "1.0.0",
```

don't really understand why this, however, always is getting me a latest commit:

```
"vendor/module": "dev-master#1.0.0",
```

Explicit tag does not add git repo to the module.
And if I remember correctly from when I used mercurial, dev-default#tag was locking the version to the "tag" but also repo was still downloaded.

Is there a way to specify a tag, but also get a repo on dev?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you want to install this package from source?

Comment: This is a metapackage that contains all of our own interconnected modules that we develop, so we need to have source for our developers to make changes. For now we ended up with using develop branch of a project and develop branch for metapackage that contains all requirements as dev-masters.

Comment: And `--prefer-source` switch will not work in this case?

Comment: There might be other 3rd party packages that might be installed with source that we will never touch. So "preferred-install" config works better. I also figured out, that sourcing a tag is not the best idea either, cause repo will be cloned in a detached head state, and we'll have to switch to master anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preferred-install`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install) config in your `composer.json` to specify that you want the source download:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/module": "1.0.0",
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "vendor/module": "source",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't think this works from inside a metapackage.
But probably the only way to do it, is for every project of ours to have our vendor to be installed from source.
       "preferred-install": {
            "vendor/*": "source",
        }

Comment: You're right, this does not work from the package itself, only from the root project `composer.json`.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as this is still the best approach for now.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually never seen anyone using the `#` notation to reference a specific tag. It was never intended to be used like that. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#i-have-locked-a-dependency-to-a-specific-commit-but-get-unexpected-results- for further details on this controversial feature.

As for dist vs. source, it is not possible to specify this for packages individually. Is there a reason you want this particular package as source only? Cause this question feels like an [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) kind of deal.

Comment: As Edi Modrić also pointed out, it is possible to specify dist. vs source individually. As I mentioned in comment under the question, our metapackage contains modules under development. But we figured that it's easier to just use develop branch of meatpackage that contains dev-master dependencies of modules being developed. And release branch to have locked tags.

Comment: You're right. I forgot we added that at some point. Your development flow seems a bit awkward. But if it works for you, all is good :-)